# HTTP Status 406 :Spring JSON request

Tags: json, spring

I am trying to get JSON data using spring 4.2.4 version. Here is the code for in my controller;

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getmessage",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,Object> getMessage(Principal prinicipal){

    List<Message>message=null;
    if(prinicipal==null){
        message=new ArrayList<Message>();

    }
    else{
        String username=prinicipal.getName();
        message=usersService.getMessage(username);
    }

    Map<String,Object> data= new HashMap<String,Object>();
    data.put("message", message);
    data.put("number", message.size());
    return data;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting an error:HTTP Status 406:"The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers."

Your usual help please?

Comment: Did you the `Accept` header in your request? You should set `Accept: application/json`

Comment: Thank you. I tried it now and same error is happening.

Comment: I pasted your method into my environment and (with a few minor changes, since I don't have Principal, Message, or usersService) it worked just fine. I'm on Spring 4.2.3, but I can't imagine that making a difference.

Comment: Oh. That is amazing! ...... What "Jackson" Jar files you used?

Comment: Hello StackOverFlow, any one who can help me with the above problem. I have been trying with almost possible suggestions mentioned and still my code is displaying same error. I tried to change my pom.xml dependency jar( jackson-mapper-1.9.x to jackson-faterxml-2.2.x) still it show the same error. Only when I add Jackson-databind it shows me file download dialog box when I try to access /getmessage page as per above code....My hibernate query returns correctly the objects the problem is converting it to json and displaying......I get stack with project deadline!!! Need help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to jackson versions.
To solve this issue just remove the following:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

from your pom file and put the following instead:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```